# What is the replacement of i_blksize member in struct inode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel, inode

I am compiling a stackable filesystem wrapfs and i got an error regardign missing member i_blksize in struct inode datastructure ? I looked up and found that after kernel version 2.6 it has been modified significantly and i_blksize has been removed. What is the replacement for that member ?

```
kunal@Baweja:~/Documents/wrapfs$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/kunal/Documents/wrapfs modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/kunal/Documents/wrapfs/fist_wrapfs.o
In file included from /home/kunal/Documents/wrapfs/fist_wrapfs.c:15:0:
/home/kunal/Documents/wrapfs/wrapfs.h: In function ‘fist_copy_attr_all’:
/home/kunal/Documents/wrapfs/wrapfs.h:203:6: error: ‘inode_t’ has no member named ‘i_blksize’
  dest->i_blksize = src->i_blksize;
      ^
/home/kunal/Documents/wrapfs/wrapfs.h:203:23: error: ‘inode_t’ has no member named ‘i_blksize’
  dest->i_blksize = src->i_blksize;
                       ^
make[2]: *** [/home/kunal/Documents/wrapfs/fist_wrapfs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/kunal/Documents/wrapfs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an unnecessary duplicate

`inode->i_blksize == (1 << inode->i_blkbits)`

Check-out this mailing [thread](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0308.0/0979.html)

Comment: @deimer I think you got my problem wrong, please see the output that I have pasted, it says ‘inode_t’ has no member named ‘i_blksize’, so I want to know what is the replacement for that member, where do I get to set the block size of data block in the inode struct (which has been rededined as inode_t using typedef struct inode inode_t;)

Comment: @RandomPerson what i was able to figure out was, that `i_blksize` has been removed as it was always equal to `1 << i_blkbits`. So you probably need to replace `i_blksize` calls with `1 << i_blkbits`  What I'm getting wrong here ?

Comment: Woops my bad :( so sorry :( I will try doing that and let you know :)